# Adding Objective C SDK into Swift 4.1 SDK

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a third party Objective-c SDK that I want to add into my custom Swift SDK. I am able to combine them as well as using some of the methods. However, when it comes to the private methods inside the Objective-c SDK, It kept returning me an Error saying, "Use of undeclared type", is there anyway around it? Thanks!

Third party objective-c class

```
@class CardReader, MeaningfulError, BluetoothDevice, DeviceEventDispatch, DeviceController;
@interface CardReaderController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly, nullable) CardReader *connectedReader;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, nullable) DeviceEventDispatch *eventDispatch;


+ (instancetype _Nonnull )sharedController;

- (BOOL)isReaderConnected;
- (void)connectAudioReader;
- (void)connectBTReader:(void (^ _Nullable)(NSArray<BluetoothDevice *> *_Nullable))availableBTReadersToConnectHandler;

- (void)disconnectReader;

@end
```

My Custom Swift class 4.1

```
@objc public protocol HardwareDelegate: class {


@objc optional func connectDeviceCompleted (status :String, error :String)

@objc optional func disConnectDeviceCompleted (status :String, error :String)
}

open class HardwareCom: NSObject {

    public static let shared = HardwareCom()
    public weak var delegate : HardwareDelegate?

     //This method is working, calls the connectAudioReader method from third party Objective-c library
     open func connectAudioReader()
    {
        print("connecting to auduio Reader");
       CardReaderController.shared().connectAudioReader()
    }

    //This method is giving me error
    open func connectBluetoothReader()
    {
     // Getting Error here, (Use of undeclared type BluetoothDevice)
     CardReaderController.shared().connectBTReader({(_ readers: [BluetoothDevice]?) -> Void in
        print("Found BT devices --> \(readers ?? "")")
      })
   }

}
```

so here is BluetoothDevice.h

```
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface BluetoothDevice : CBPeripheral

@end
```

The class is included in the SDK, but for whatever reason swift is not able to locate it.

Comment: Hi, I have edit my question. It's Frameworks.

Comment: Make sure BluetoothDevice is `@objc public` (or `@objc Open`), and its desired methods too (likely `init` for instance). Better show both the ObjC code and the Swift code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have edited the my question to show both classes.

Comment: No, you have not shown how or where BluetoothDevice is declared. It sounds like you have simply forgotten to import `"BluetoothDevice.h"` in your swift bridging header.

Comment: The BluetoothDevice is not included in the third party library, which is why I assume it's a private class. I don't see the BluetoothDevice anywhere in the Objective-c SDK

Answer (score 0):

You have a Swift bridging header consisting of `#import` statements for Objective-C header files. It sounds like you have forgotten to import `"BluetoothDevice.h"` or whatever Objective-C header file declares BluetoothDevice.

Comment: I am creating a Custom SDK myself. So there is no need to use Bridge header files, so I just need to make sure the modules are enabled in the settings. I am able to use all the public classes. BluetoothDevice.h, I can't find it anywhere in the third party objective-c SDK, which I assume it's a private class.

Comment: It's not about "private", it's about visibility. You need to import _something_ that either is or imports the file where BluetoothDevice is declared. Otherwise your Swift code doesn't know about it.

Comment: I am using a third party sdk framework. I am not able to find the declaration class of BluetoothDevice anywhere inside the third party SDK besides it is being called by CardReaderController. When I use an Objective-c app to test the third party SDK, I am able to access BluetoothDevice, but once I moved to swift, swift is not able to find BluetoothDevice, in seift I am able to access all the other classes so bridging isn’t the issue, hence I was wondering if there could be some other settings that I need to modify in my swift project settings.

Comment: Well, it would obviously be a lot easier to answer that question if you were to tell us what framework this is, so that we can see for ourselves. As it is, you're just asking for a guess. My guess is that you're just out of luck: this framework's API is not constructed in a way that makes the BluetoothDevice class accessible from Swift. You might ask whoever wrote the framework to look into that. Meanwhile, as you've already implied, you might have to write that part of the code in Objective-C.

Comment: Well, it's not clear to me that we solved anything. It would be really helpful to see the framework in question... I have a sense that Swift came along and caught this framework with its pants down, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you @matt I have updated the question to include the class since it's exposed in the SDK now.

The sdk is for https://www.anywherecommerce.com

Comment: But ANPBluetoothDevice != BluetoothDevice. I don't get it.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any public documentation so I really can't help any further, sorry.

Comment: Right, yea their doc isn't very helpful which is why I am kinda stuck as well doing try and error. That was my bad, should be BluetoothDevice. Thank you!

Comment: OK, so you are saying you _do_ see a file called _BluetoothDevice.h_ in the framework? Then my answer is right: you need to `import` that file in your bridging header. Might need to write `#import <MyFramework/BluetoothDevice.h>`, might need to set header search paths in build settings, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, I do see the BluetoothDevice.h after they expose it. I tried to do <MyFramework/BluetoothDevice.h> in my bridging header, it returns the same error, for whatever reason it's not being able to find that class. Every classes that inherits NSObject, I am able to use them except BluetoothDevice.h which inherits CBPeripheral which comes from Apple's CoreBluetooth SDK. Well Thanks for the help!

Comment: Like I say, I can't seem to download this framework so I can't try it out. But surely others are using it????

Comment: That I am not sure, but yea worst comes worst migrating my swift code to objective-c which I tested it work